# PySpark: casting string as timestamp gives wrong time

Tags: string, pyspark, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I use the following code to cast a string type time `timstm_hm` to timestamp time `timstm_hm_timestamp`. Here is the code.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unix_timestamp
df = df.withColumn('timstm_hm_timestamp', unix_timestamp(col('timstm_hm'), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm").cast("timestamp"))
```

Here are the results.

```
-------------------------------------------------
|   timstm_hm         |   timstm_hm_timestamp   |  
-------------------------------------------------
|2018-02-08 11:04     | 2018-01-08 11:04:00     | 
-------------------------------------------------
|2018-02-27 20:34     | 2018-01-27 20:34:00     | 
-------------------------------------------------
|2018-02-23 19:47     | 2018-01-23 19:47:00     | 
-------------------------------------------------
```

Why there is one month difference between the conversion? It is very weird as it works for month January but not since February.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to **replace** `mm` with capitals `MM`.

Refer to java date format for more info: [Javasimpledate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unix_timestamp
df.withColumn('timstm_hm_timestamp', unix_timestamp(col('timstm_hm'), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").cast("timestamp")).show()

+----------------+-------------------+
|       timstm_hm|timstm_hm_timestamp|
+----------------+-------------------+
|2018-02-08 11:04|2018-02-08 11:04:00|
+----------------+-------------------+
```

Also, you can achieve same output by using **just** `to_timestamp` with **capital** `MM`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
df.withColumn("timestm_hm_timestamp", to_timestamp("timstm_hm","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" )).show()

+----------------+--------------------+
|       timstm_hm|timestm_hm_timestamp|
+----------------+--------------------+
|2018-02-08 11:04| 2018-02-08 11:04:00|
+----------------+--------------------+
```